# "thread panicked while processing panic. aborting" error while executing test through GeckoDriver Firefox and Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, geckodriver, panic

I am new to coding and web scraping. However I already encountered error while just tried to open a url with browser by simply code.

Source code

```
import sys
import urllib.request
import importlib
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
importlib.reload(sys)
url = 'http://www.python.org'
driver = webdriver.Firefox() 
driver.get(url)
browser.close()
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/桌面/Old Data/WS/111.py", line 9, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 3221225501
```

Here is the log of Geckodriver

```
1533786140718   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.21.0 (c7d3022be6420de1ca4076d932aa32b299f3ea10 2018-06-14)
thread panicked while processing panic. aborting.
1533786140734   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:2472
thread panicked while processing panic. aborting.
```

Comment: 4 of your imports are entirely unnecessary.. and you didn't mention the version of Firefox you are attempting to use

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/??/Old Data/WS/111.py", line 9, in <module>
  .
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 3221225501
```

...implies that the **GeckoDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Firefox Browser** session.

You need to take care of a couple of issues as follows:

- As per your code block importing `sys`, `urllib.request`, `importlib` and `time` was unnecessary, so you can remove them.
- From the *error trace log* it is evident you are executing your `@Test` as an **Administrator** which must be avoided. Always execute your `@Test` as a ***non-root*** user.
- You are possibly using **Windows XP** as the underlying **OS**.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### `thread panicked while processing panic`, Rust, Panic and WinXP

As per the *release notes* of [GeckoDriver v0.11.0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.11.0) of *2016-10-10*:

- Changed Rust compiler version to 1.12 (beta) temporarily because of [trouble linking Musl binaries](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34978)
- Replaced `env_logger` logging facility with the `slog` package, causing the `RUST_LOG` environment variable to no longer have any affect.
- Updated the WebDriver Rust library to version 0.15

Moving forward as per the *release notes* of [GeckoDriver v0.14.0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.14.0) of *2017-01-31*:

- Stacktraces are now included when the error originates from within the Rust stack.

Now in [Windows XP doesn't have ConditionVariables, which notify requires via mpsc channels](https://github.com/passcod/notify/issues/79) @retep998 mentioned:

> Windows XP support is super shady. While `libstd` does not link to any functions that are unavailable on Windows XP, certain std functionality does load those functions at runtime and will panic if they don't exist. It's quite likely that somewhere `rsnotify` depends on some functionality that requires an API that isn't available on Windows XP.

But it seems as per [Panic broken on Windows XP](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34538) @alexcrichton mentioned:

> When a thread panics it attempts to run its panic hook, but that panic hook is protected by an RwLock which is in turn not implemented on XP. That means that when panicking you'll panic immediately as you attempt to acquire an rwlock.

Finally, [MUSL target doesn't link on nightly](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34978) seems to get resolved in `rustc 1.12.0-nightly (a005b6785 2016-08-02)`

### Conclusion

With the current releases of *Selenium v3.14.0*, *GeckoDriver v0.21.0* and *Firefox v61.0.2* execute your `@Tests` as a *non-root* user on *non WinXP* OS (e.g. *Win7*, *Win8* or *Win10*) which will solve your issue.